# Git Bash displaing wrong Name

Tags: git, git-bash

When I open git bash there is displayed a wrong user name and I would like to change it

it looks a bit like this:

WrongName@abc MINGW64 ~

I would like to have myName there. I alredy tryed git `config -global user.email "Name@abc.com"` and this dose alow work when i check `git config global user.email`.
but it's not changing the thing i want to change. i alow tried user.name

Comment: It's probably a local setting not a global one, try `git config user.email "Name@abc.com"`. Local config succeeds global

Comment: Actually that looks like bash's environment (whatever is set up with $PS1). So WrongName is probably the username. Try this: `echo $USER $HOSTNAME`.